# PowerShell class array of strings syntax

Tags: class, powershell, syntax

I have the following class, but instead of a [String] member variable I need to declare an array of Strings. What's the syntax?

```
class SomeClass{
  [String] $patterns;

  SomeClass(){
    $this.patterns = "Maintenance Code","Page \d+ of";
  }

  [Bool]SomeMethod([string]$txt){}
}
```

Comment: `[System.String[]]`

Comment: Thanks, that works

Comment: Some people care for judging instead of just answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as PetSerAl said [System.String[]] but [String[]] is just fine.

It's also mentioned in help about_arrays.

```
To create a strongly typed array, that is, an array that can contain only
    values of a particular type, cast the variable as an array type, such 
    as string[], long[], or int32[]. To cast an array, precede the variable
    name with an array type enclosed in brackets. For example, to create a
    32-bit integer array named $ia containing four integers (1500, 2230, 3350,
    and 4000), type:

        [int32[]]$ia = 1500,2230,3350,4000
```